# Student class and Menu class not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

this is Students.cs
It is showing an error "NullReferenceException was unhandled" at line ---- Console.WriteLine("Student{0}: {1}, {2:P} {3}", i+1, stuList[i].studentName,stuList[i].studentPercentage, stuList[i].studentLetterGrade);

Can I get help finding the error with this two classes
    private static int studentCount = 0;

```
    // Instance variables go here
    private string studentName;
    private double studentPercentage;
    private string studentLetterGrade;
    private Grade test = new Grade(0);
    private Grade hwQz = new Grade(700);

    //Default Constructor Method
    public Student()
    {
    }//end of Student Constructor method

    public Student(string name)
    {
        //if(name.Length == 0)
            SetStudentName("Jane Doe");
        //else
            //SetStudentName(name);
    }//end of Overloaded Constructor method

    public Student(string name, int percent, string letter)
    {
        SetStudentName(name);
        SetStudentPercent(percent);
        SetStudentLetter(letter);
    }//end of Overloaded Constructor method

    //Class Methods

    // retrieve the student count
    public static int GetStudentCount()
    {
        return studentCount;
    }//end of GetStudentCount method

    // set the student count
    public static void SetStudentCount(int newStudentCount)
    {
        studentCount = newStudentCount;
    }//end of SetStudentCount method

    // list students
    public static void ListStudents(Student[] stuList)
    {
        //Clear Screen
        Console.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student{0}: {1}, {2:P} {3}", i+1, stuList[i].studentName,stuList[i].studentPercentage, stuList[i].studentLetterGrade);
        }
    }

    // Instance methods go here

    // retrieve the Student name
    public string GetStudentName()
    {
        return studentName;
    }//end of GetStudentName method

    // set the Student name
    public void SetStudentName(string newName)
    {
        studentName = newName;
    }//end of SetStudentName method

    // retrieve the Student percent
    public double GetStudentPercent()
    {
        return studentPercentage;
    }//end of GetStudentPercent method

    // set the Student address
    public void SetStudentPercent(double newPercent)
    {
        studentPercentage = newPercent;
    }//end of SetStudentPercent method

    // retrieve the Student Letter
    public string GetStudentLetter()
    {
        return studentLetterGrade;
    }//end of GetStudentLetter method

    // set the Student letter
    public void SetStudentLetter(string newLetter)
    {
        studentLetterGrade = "A+";
    }//end of SetStudentLetter method

    public void EnterStudentScores()
    {
        test.EnterScores("Test");
        hwQz.EnterScores("Homework & Quiz");
        //Store the overall score in a temp variable
        double gradePercent = ((50 * test.GetGradePercent()) + (50 * hwQz.GetGradePercent()));
        //Using typecasting to force a double into an int data type
        SetStudentPercent(gradePercent);
        SetStudentLetter(test.GetLetterGrade(gradePercent));
    }
}
```

}

The above Students.cs is connected with Menu.cs

```
 bool runApp = true;
        Student[] students = new Student[35];
        //Application loop
        while (runApp)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\tGrade Book Menu\n");
            Console.WriteLine("\t1) Add Student");
            Console.WriteLine("\t2) Enter Student Grades");
            Console.WriteLine("\t3) List Student Grades");
            Console.Write("\nEnter Selection or Press Escape to exit: ");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                runApp = false;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (key.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad1:
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        //Get the current student count stored in the Student Class variable
                        int indexForNewStudent = Student.GetStudentCount();
                        indexForNewStudent = 0;
                        Console.Write("\nEnter Student Name: ");
                        //Instantiate a Student object and place it in the array of Student objects called student
                        students[indexForNewStudent] = new Student(Console.ReadLine()); //Call overloaded constructor
                        //Increment Student count
                        Student.SetStudentCount(indexForNewStudent + 2); //Add to index to account for new student
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad2:
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nEnter the Student Number.  Use List Students to get Student Number.");
                        int studentNumber = 0; //Temporary variable to hold the student number to enter grades
                        //Test the entered string is a number and between 1 and 30
                        if ((int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out studentNumber)) && (studentNumber >= 1) &&
                             (studentNumber <= 30))
                        {
                            //In the event a student has not been added this code will crash
                            if (Student.GetStudentCount() > 0) //Has a student been added?
                                students[studentNumber - 1].EnterStudentScores(); //Subtract 1 from enterd number for array index
                            else
                                Console.WriteLine("A student has not been added");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Student Number.  Enter a number from 1 to 30");
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.NumPad3:
                    case ConsoleKey.D3:
                        Student.ListStudents(students);
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid Menu Selection");
                        break;
                }
                Console.Write("Press a key to return to Menu");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        Console.Write("\nExiting Application.  Press any key to close window... ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

This code is also connect with the following Grade.cs

```
   private double[] earnedScores = new double[30];
    private double pointTotal = 0;
    private int scoresEntered = 0;

    public Grade()
    {
    }

    public Grade(double total)
    {
        pointTotal = total;
    }

    public void SetPointTotal(int total)
    {
        pointTotal = (double)total; //using double to type cast an int into a double
    }
    public void SetPointTotal(double total) // Overloaded method for SetPointTotal
    {
        pointTotal = total;
    }

    public void EnterScores(string scoreType)
    {
        //Loop that lets the user enter up to 30 scores
        //the loop ends after 30 entries or Q is pressed
        do
        {
            Console.Clear(); //Clear screen
            //scoreType is a string passed in that prints to the screen to help user know what scores are being entered
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Scores", scoreType); 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter up to {0} scores or Q to quit.", earnedScores.Length);
            Console.Write("Enter score{0}: ", scoresEntered + 1);
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            //Validate user entered string stored in input.
            //Return -2 if Q was pressed and -1 if the string is invalid
            double inputNumber = ValidateScore(input);
            if (inputNumber == -1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid entry.  Please enter a valid positive score.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            else if (inputNumber == -2)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                earnedScores[scoresEntered] = inputNumber;
                scoresEntered++;
            }
        } while(scoresEntered < earnedScores.Length);
    }

    public void DisplayScore(string scoreType)
    {
        //scoreType is a string passed in that prints to the screen to help user know what scores are being displayed
        Console.WriteLine("{0} Scores", scoreType);
        //Loop thru the earnedScores array and print each element's value
        for (int i = 0; i < scoresEntered; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Score{0}: {1}", i + 1, earnedScores[i]);
        }
    }

    public double ValidateScore(string inText)
    {
        int dotCount = 0; //Variable to hold the count of decimals
        char[] temp = inText.ToCharArray(); //char array to hold incoming string

        if (inText.Length > 0) //text is not blank if length greater than zero
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inText.Length; i++) //loop thru each character and test contents
            {
                if (temp[i] == '.') //is it a decimal
                {
                    dotCount += 1; //dotCount++; does the same thing
                    if (dotCount > 1) //More than 1 decimal invalid
                        return -1;
                }
                else if (temp[i] == '-') //if Negative sign
                {
                    if (i != 0) //If Negative is not 1st element of array then invalid
                        return -1;
                }
                else if (!char.IsNumber(temp[i])) //If character is not a number
                {
                    if (temp[i] == 'Q' || temp[i] == 'q') //If Q or q then exit loop
                    {
                        return -2;
                    }
                    else //Any other letter invalid
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            return -1; //Blank was entered
        } 
        return Convert.ToDouble(inText);
    }

    public double GetGradePercent()
    {
        double totalEarnedPoints = 0; //Start with zero
        //Add all elements of the array to total
        for (int i = 0; i < scoresEntered; i++)
        {
            totalEarnedPoints += earnedScores[i];
        }
        //Return grade percentage by dividing earned points by total points
        return totalEarnedPoints / pointTotal;
    }

    public string GetLetterGrade(double percentage)
    {
        //Incoming parameter will be in decimal format. Example 90% will be 0.90
        percentage *= 100; //Multiply incoming percentage by 100 to move decimal point scaling number from 0 to 100

        if (percentage >= 97.0)
        {
            return "A+";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 97) && (percentage >= 93))
        {
            return "A";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 93) && (percentage >= 90))
        {
            return "A-";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 90) && (percentage >= 87))
        {
            return "B+";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 87) && (percentage >= 83))
        {
            return "B";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 83) && (percentage >= 80))
        {
            return "B-";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 80) && (percentage >= 77))
        {
            return "C+";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 77) && (percentage >= 70))
        {
            return "C";
        }
        else if ((percentage < 70) && (percentage >= 60))
        {
            return "D";
        }
        else
        {
            return "E";
        }
    }

    public void ClearScores()
    {
        scoresEntered = 0; //Clear number of scores previously entered
        //Reset all elements of the array back to zero
        for (int i = 0; i < earnedScores.Length; i++)
        {
            earnedScores[i] = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where are you calling `ListStudents`?

Comment: in the students.cs means the first code

Answer (score 0):

In your add student code you have a couple of problems

```
indexForNewStudent = 0;
```

This means you will always be overwriting the first student rather than adding a new one.

```
//Increment Student count
Student.SetStudentCount(indexForNewStudent + 2); //Add to index to account for new student
```

The +2 here means that your student count will be 1 greater than the number of students, meaning that the ListStudents function will then try to access a student that hasn't been added yet. It should be +1

Comment: Which bit isn't working? I tried your code with those changes and I could add students (it was always the same name due to the commented out code).

Comment: Option 2 from the menu is not working. I am not able to add student grades.

Comment: I really recommend using a debugger. To get you started look at this code `&& (studentNumber <= 1) && (studentNumber >= 30)` - can you pick a number that satisfies these conditions?

Comment: I used debugger but it is not working. If I enter any number between 1 and 30 it shows an error message " Invalid Student Numbers. Enter number between 1 and 30"

Comment: I added grade.cs which is connected with student.cs and menu.cs

Comment: Look again at that code. It is saying the student number must be **less** than or equal to one **and** **greater** than or equal to 30. There are no numbers that can satisfy that condition.

Comment: what should be the condition for checking student number

Comment: I changed the condition but it shows an error message "A student has not been added"

Comment: Look at the code that causes the message to show up. Why are you checking that the student count is less than zero before you add grades? 1. The student count can never be less than zero. 2. If the student count was less than zero you would want to display the error, not add grades, so you have your if test the wrong way around.

Comment: I changed the code. After the change, I am able to enter student name, grades for exams but the final grade shows "A+ infinity". It seems the following for loop is not working. for (int i = 0; i < studentCount; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Student{0}: {1}, {2:P} {3}", i+1, stuList[i].studentName,stuList[i].studentPercentage, stuList[i].studentLetterGrade);
        }